# Images not resizing in browsers

Tags: html, css, image, browser, hover

These images don't resize on any browser. What am I doing wrong and how can I resize a background-image?

The image tag:

```
<table class="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="TMR Library.html"><div id="Library"></div></a><img src="DividerTransparent.png" id="Divider">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="TMR Contact.html"><div id="Contact"></div></a><img src="DividerTransparent.png" id="Divider">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="TMR About.html"><div id="About"></div></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS:

```css
#Library {

background-image: url('LibraryTransparent.png');
height: 70px;
width: 120px;
border-style: none;
}

#Library:hover {

background-image: url('LibraryHoverTrans.png');
height: 70px;
width: 120px;
}
```

The CSS is the same for the 3 images.

Comment: You have specified a height and a width in px. You are experiencing the expected behavior. Try moving to % based sizes.

Comment: percentages didn't work the images didn't even appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then your other option would be to put your image into a photo manipulation program and make the image your specified size by default.
As a general rule of thumb, HTML and CSS do not manipulate images very well to begin with, they can do some manipulation, but can't guarantee what the result will look like. 
(an example would be if you wanted to make the image smaller, the browser could either cut the full image down to the size specified, or shrink down the image)

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question now... You want a fixed container size of sorts, but have a background image which takes 100% of it... Here's an example that uses the same picture at 3 different sizes.

**HTML**

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
<div id="baz"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#foo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/300/300);
}

#bar {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/300/300);
}

#baz {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image:  url(http://placekitten.com/300/300);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DLnTS/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use percent widths instead of fixed widths.

Comment: I need the images to be exactly that size in pixels, how can I do that with percentages?

Comment: @user2784439 with math.

Comment: @user2784439 How do **how can I resize** and **exactly that size in pixels** go together?

Comment: @ Mike Corcorandidn't even work images aren't even appearing now

Comment: @user2784439 Yes I'm serious. You tell us that you want the images to be exactly that size while at the same time you want the images to resize? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Stijn yes I want them to resize - to the specified dimensions in pixels (those exact dimensions), think about it

Comment: I think there's some confusion here with people not reading the original question properly, and not looking at the code properly. These are the background images using within the empty DIVs, not the images to the side of the anchor tags. 

CSS3 can do this using background-size, but CSS2 and below can't.
If you can't use CSS3 in your project you'll have to replace those DIVs with IMG tags instead, then if you apply CSS sizes to them they will resize. You shouldn't have div tags inside an anchor anyway, it's not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the css `background-size: 100%;`

CSS3 is better with  `background-size:cover`

Comment: I need the images to be exactly that size in pixels